# Insert json data in table of sql and display it in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Below is the data I insert into db

```
  insert into faq (title, question, answer) values 
('Common', 'Question 1', '[{"Step 1": "Here", "Step 2": "Heree", "Step 3": "Hereee"}]'),
('Common', 'Question 2', 'Answer for question 2');
```

This is how I parse JSON in dart language in my faq model dart file

```
List<FAQ> faqFromJson(String str) =>
    List<FAQ>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => FAQ.fromJson(x)));

String faqToJson(List<FAQ> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class FAQ {
  final int? id;
  final String? title;
  final String? question;
  final dynamic answer;
  final String? image;
  final DateTime? createdDate;
  final DateTime? updateDate;

  FAQ({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.question,
    this.answer,
    this.image,
    this.createdDate,
    this.updateDate,
  });

  factory FAQ.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => FAQ(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        question: json["question"],
        answer: json["answer"],
        image: json["image"],
        createdDate: json["createdDate"] == null
            ? null
            : DateTime.parse(json["createdDate"]),
        updateDate: json["updateDate"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "question": question,
        "answer": answer,
        "image": image,
        "createdDate": createdDate?.toIso8601String(),
        "updateDate": updateDate,
      };
}
```

This is how I display the question and answer in flutter

```
    Widget faqlist(BuildContext context, Size size, List<dynamic> data) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: data.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data[index].question),
              subtitle: Text(data[index].answer),
            );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

The problem is now is display like this [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kjhW.png), I don't want the answer display like json type. I wish to display like this [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zm7r.png).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of your answer. Here is dynamic which is converted to String and you are not decoding the String from json to use it as an object.

```
class Answer {
  Map<String, String> answers;

  Answer({required this. answers});

  factory Answer.fromJson(String jsonString) {
    Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    return Answer(
      steps: Map<String, String>.from(json),
    );
  }
}
```

By replacing the dynamic type by the type answer you have now a CustomType that accepts any number of answers in your json and translate it to a map of Strings.

Don't forget to update your factory when creating your FAQ object :

`answer: Answer.fromJson(json["answer"])`

Little bonus, override a toString method in the `Answer` object so you can log it / print it easily

```
 @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Answer{steps: $steps}';
  }
```